# YEOMAN - angular-full-stack Facebook login does not work on Heroku, but works locally

Tags: angularjs, facebook, heroku, angular-fullstack

I created an app with the "angular-full-stack" generator from YEOMAN.
I have here a Login auth via Facebook. It works in localhost but not when I deploy the app on Heroku.

Locally I have the facebook api key and secret in local.env.js , and for Heroku I can test the key , secret and domain is ok:

heroku config: give me this:

```
heroku config
debocaenboca Config Vars
DOAMAIN:         http://debocaenboca.herokuapp.com
DOMAIN:          debocaenboca.herokuapp.com
FACEBOOK_ID:     id
FACEBOOK_SECRET: secret
MONGOLAB_URI:    mongodburi
```

The log is not showing any error or something that indicates something wrong.

```
2015-10-25T21:07:56.577904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/facebook" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=3fe0b220-e2ea-4265-8c55-8a3ccff9f978 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=358
2015-10-25T21:07:56.573658+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /auth/facebook 302 4ms - 0b
2015-10-25T21:07:58.668213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/debocaenboca.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAKaXScpO5h1JkL4YU52_vYiNafT8IVBJXMe1e5_MTCeJI72We40j0KqD-v-O5KAulqhduHckfq43_150oZL_3n-YawA4yR41VntU3gOJolNqUSD7btEXTiEYgDJK4k9Zw5EBoIqy9wdsa0JON4F0X7Zjkp0-RED-hjLX2yN4G1iWl-xIvkOS3NJN8TbcAFJYZeXV50ODZquz9rGLhGoTBIKH_rcQb4by-OpctOL0KJljz0wANwLsGZaFUruwFQ4lfTeBQhNh0SRFZAF33wjX3IF0z4YrZge7lrfYJxz9t9plCunEicFhcoxiuju1_eJ0I" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=d60e27d6-0a76-4a8c-b3c5-0ef33aeb4388 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1281
2015-10-25T21:07:58.663767+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /debocaenboca.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAKaXScpO5h1JkL4YU52_vYiNafT8IVBJXMe1e5_MTCeJI72We40j0KqD-v-O5KAulqhduHckfq43_150oZL_3n-YawA4yR41VntU3gOJolNqUSD7btEXTiEYgDJK4k9Zw5EBoIqy9wdsa0JON4F0X7Zjkp0-RED-hjLX2yN4G1iWl-xIvkOS3NJN8TbcAFJYZeXV50ODZquz9rGLhGoTBIKH_rcQb4by-OpctOL0KJljz0wANwLsGZaFUruwFQ4lfTeBQhNh0SRFZAF33wjX3IF0z4YrZge7lrfYJxz9t9plCunEicFhcoxiuju1_eJ0I 200 2ms
2015-10-25T21:07:59.116674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app/ac9f3c61.vendor.js" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=1d8d304a-11c3-4a35-aff3-f24d40f3ac9d fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=236
2015-10-25T21:07:59.108644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app/995998e6.app.js" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=bb0017f6-12de-4908-bfd2-c6b287c91e25 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=235
2015-10-25T21:07:59.089261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=MvDvVraJB6lh4PlZAAAF" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=f41adefe-7787-4c34-87b3-22bef4e258a7 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10226ms status=101 bytes=175
2015-10-25T21:07:59.102183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app/a886b058.app.css" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=b37a0e65-1210-4e42-aaac-7e76a77084a3 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=234
2015-10-25T21:07:59.126797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app/71c590b0.vendor.css" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=ac7e748b-a0cd-4799-8b15-1e1d6c56c016 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=236
2015-10-25T21:07:59.725472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/things" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=70d97f2e-e429-4852-afe3-94fec79ec549 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=129
2015-10-25T21:07:59.718879+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/things 304 3ms
2015-10-25T21:07:59.726324+00:00 app[web.1]: [undefined:undefined] CONNECTED
2015-10-25T21:07:59.729628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1445807253844-0" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=2815ccbd-6375-4ac5-a9a9-dbaa66e58255 fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=306
2015-10-25T21:08:00.384888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1445807254261-1&sid=VZ51UHynhfSHDjClAAAG" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=c0649d8c-1426-40f9-9094-15b54437d69e fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=208
2015-10-25T21:08:01.372678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1445807254889-2&sid=VZ51UHynhfSHDjClAAAG" host=debocaenboca.herokuapp.com request_id=4d79ae47-49aa-490e-b490-4bf1b7a68b4e fwd="181.114.227.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=459ms status=200 bytes=207
```

Thanks!

Comment: I could solve the problem, in Heroku I had the DOMAIN set and seems the redirect from facebook had twice times the app host name: something like this: "debocaenboca.herokuapp.com/debocaenboca.herokuapp.com/........ ", so I removed the DOMAIN from Heroku and now works fine.